# Proving that $\partial W \subseteq V^c.$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $V \subseteq_{\text {open}} \mathbb C$ and $W \subseteq V$ be a connected component of $V.$ Then show that $\partial W \subseteq V^c.$

I have tried but couldn't quite able to show it. Could anybody please give me some hint?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: what's your definition of $\partial W$? When you say you have tried, what did you try?

Comment: If $\partial W$ contains a point of $V$ what can you say about $W \cup B(z,r)$ for small $r$?

Comment: Can you show that $W$ is open? Do you see if that helps?

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani in any locally connected topological space connected components are always open. But what to do with that?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy$:$ $W \cup B(z,r) \subseteq V$ for small enough $r \gt 0$ and it is connected and hence we should have $W \cup B(z,r) = W,$ by the maximality of $W.$ Therefore $z \in B(z,r) \subseteq W,$ a contradiction since $W$ is open being a connected component of a locally connected topological space.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani got it. Thanks.